# How to find out the general formula of a sequence with a nonlinear recursion relation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, nonlinear-optimization, recursion

For example, is there a way to find out the general formula for a sequence $\{a_n\}$ with $a_{i}=a_{i-1}\times a_{i-2}+a_{i-3}$ and the values of $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are arbitrary?

Or generally speaking, is there a way to solve all kinds of nonlinear but polynomial recursion relation?

Answer (score 1):

There are techiques to solve *a few* non-linear recurrences I know of. Not for "general polynomial" ones, sorry.

Comment: How about the one I meantioned above?